# Multiple arguments for function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, getelementbyid

I have a table where it makes a whole row clickable when a link is added to any cell. What I would like to do is add this script to multiple tables on a page. The problem is the script will only work with one table since it can only be used with id and not class css. How do I add multiple table ids?

```
      window.onload = function(){
      ConvertRowsToLinks("results-table"); //My table id
      // ConvertRowToLinks("results-table", "results-table2");
      // I would like to add results-table2, results-table3 etc...

  }

  function ConvertRowsToLinks(xTableId){

    var rows = document.getElementById(xTableId).getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      var link = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("a")
      if(link.length == 1){
        rows[i].onclick = new Function("document.location.href='" + link[0].href + "'");
        rows[i].onmouseover = new Function("this.className='highlight'");
        rows[i].onmouseout = new Function("this.className=''");
      }
    }


    ConvertSideRowsToLinks("sidebar-table");
  }

  function ConvertSideRowsToLinks(xTableId){

    var rows = document.getElementById(xTableId).getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      var link = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("a")
      if(link.length == 1){
        rows[i].onclick = new Function("document.location.href='" + link[0].href + "'");
        rows[i].onmouseover = new Function("this.className='highlight'");
        rows[i].onmouseout = new Function("this.className=''");
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also slice *arguments* this way you can pass as many ids as you want, and you don't have to create array explicite:

```
  function ConvertSideRowsToLinks()
  {
    var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    for (var key in ids)
    {
        var table =  document.getElementById(ids[key])
        var rows =table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
          var link = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("a")
          if(link.length == 1){
            rows[i].onclick = new Function("document.location.href='" + link[0].href + "'");
            rows[i].onmouseover = new Function("this.className='highlight'");
            rows[i].onmouseout = new Function("this.className=''");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class as :

```
//Html code
<a class="test" name="Name 1"></a>
<a class="test" name="Name 2"></a>
<a class="test" name="Name 3"></a>

// access like
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass an array and iterate over it:

```
function ConvertTablesRowsToLinks(tableIds){
  tableIds.forEach( ConvertRowsToLinks);
```

}

```
function ConvertRowsToLinks(xTableId){
    var i; // variable i should be declared otherwise is leaking to global namespace.
    var rows = document.getElementById(xTableId).getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      var link = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("a")
      if(link.length == 1){
      rows[i].onclick = new Function("document.location.href='" + link[0].href + "'");
      rows[i].onmouseover = new Function("this.className='highlight'");
      rows[i].onmouseout = new Function("this.className=''");
    }
  }
```